# Kotlin foreach object

Tags: arrays, for-loop, kotlin, foreach

I have a object class,

```
object Examples {
    const val E = 1
    const val X = 2
    const val A = 3
    const val M = 4
    const val P = 5
    const val L = 6
}
```

if I use

```
Examples.E
```

it will reference the relevant const val, but how can I iterate over each val without calling them individually?

Comment: @user yeah my bad, was just a example >.< I'll remove now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, best way to do this is use [Enum class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html).

But you also could implement `Iterable` interface on yours object.  And after this you will be able to use `forEach`/`map`/`fold`/`filter` and other useful `Iterable` extension functions

```
object Examples : Iterable<Int> {

    const val E = 1
    const val X = 2
    const val A = 3
    const val M = 4
    const val P = 5
    const val L = 6

    override fun iterator(): Iterator<Int> {
        return object : Iterator<Int> {

            private var i = 1

            override fun hasNext(): Boolean = i <= 6

            override fun next(): Int {
                return when (i++) {
                    1 -> E
                    2 -> X
                    3 -> A
                    4 -> M
                    5 -> P
                    6 -> L
                    else -> error("No such element exeption")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Examples.forEach {
    println(it)
}
```

Comment: Implementing `Iterable` is a great idea. However, I'd suggest storing the variables that you want to iterate over in some sort of collection instead of pattern matching, since it'd be a little less boilerplate

Comment: Yes, I agree. It's funny solution. I just want to illustrate that objects can implement interfaces and by implementing `Iterable ` you can use power of existing extension functions in Kotlin.

Comment: No, I'm not saying it's funny or odd at all, I just thought it'd be easier to say `val vals = listOf(E, X, A ...)` and then `fun iterator() = vals.iterator()`

Comment: All (almost all?) of those Iterable functions are also available for Array, which is what Enum.values is.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want an enum:

```
enum class Example(val intVal: Int) {
    E(1), X(2), A(3), M(4), P(5), L(6);
}
```

You can access specific values like `Example.E.intVal`. To get a collection of all the values, you can do `Example.values()` or `enumValues<Example>()`

Answer (score 0):

With Kotlin, you could use reflection to get all values inside an object.

However, did you consider using an [Enum class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html)? This seems like it would fit your use case better:

```
enum class Letter {
        A,
        B,
        C
}
```

You can get all possible values for `Letter` using

```
Letter.values()
```

Or if what you want is to be able to reference repeated elements in order, you could use an array, or just a string, if the elements are always letters.

Also keep in mind you have two values called "E" defined, which wouldn't work.